# Assign input box value from another input box on select click in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, input

I have a form where there are 5 fields, 3 of them has a value like hours,days and lease which has default values, then one selectbox and another empty input box, my code is like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hr').change(function() {
    $('#mytexts').val($('#hours').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="hours" value="23" readonly/>
<input type="text" id="days" value="33" readonly/>
<input type="text" id="lease" value="33" readonly/>


<select name="hours" id="hr">
  <option value="" onchange="myFunctionhours(this)">---Select---</option>
  <option value="hours">Hours</option>
  <option value="days">Days</option>
  <option value="lease">Lease</option>

</select>

<input type="text" name="crate" id="mytexts" value="" readonly/>
```

When a value is selected From the selectBox I want to empty input box to get values from the 3 input boxes accordingly, now in what I did I am able to only get the value of hours box, can anyone please tell me how to do this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to take the the value from the change event , by useing `event.target.value`  then assign its follwing value to the result input as follow :

```
  $('#hr').change(function(event) {
    let selected = event.target.value;
     if(selected) $('#mytexts').val($("#"+selected).val());
  });
```

see below wokring snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hr').change(function(event) {
    let selected = event.target.value;
    $("#choise").html(selected)
    if(selected) $('#mytexts').val($("#"+selected).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="hours" value="23" readonly/>
<input type="text" id="days" value="33" readonly/>
<input type="text" id="lease" value="33" readonly/>

<br /><br />
<select name="hours" id="hr">
  <option value="" onchange="myFunctionhours(this)">---Select---</option>
  <option value="hours">Hours</option>
  <option value="days">Days</option>
  <option value="lease">Lease</option>

</select>
<br /><br />
<input type="text" name="crate" id="mytexts" value="" readonly/> <span id="choise"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the value of dropdown value as query selector in JQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hr').change(function() {
    $('#mytexts').val($("#"+$('#hr').val()).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: null -->
```